# Sharing dependency property in C# (WPF) between two classes

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I want two share a `DepedencyProperty` between to classes using `AddOwner` (any other approach is welcome), e.g.

```
class ClassA : DependencyObject
{
    public int Number
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(NumberProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NumberProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty NumberProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Number", typeof(int), typeof(ClassA),
             new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0,
                 FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
}
```

and

```
class ClassB : DependencyObject
{
    public int Number
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(NumberProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NumberProperty, value); }
    }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty NumberProperty =
        ClassA.NumberProperty.AddOwner(typeof(ClassB),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
}
```

like described [here](http://csharpsimplified.wordpress.com/category/wpf/dependency-property/). As you might guess: Of course it doesn't work. That makes perfect sense, because it would make it impossible to create multiple instances of the same class that all have their "own" dependency property.

How do I make sure that **all classes** (and especially **all instances**) of `ClassA`, `ClassB` and any other class which refers to the property are talking about the exact same property (and therefore **value**)? A [Singleton](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternSingleton.aspx#_self1) is no option, since `Class A` is a `MainWindow` and `Class B` is an `UserControl` (protected constructors are therefore not possible).

Regards,
Ben

Comment: Can you explain what "doesn't work"?

Comment: Can you also explain why "it would make it impossible to create multiple instances of the same class that all have their 'own' dependency property"?

Comment: Sure, If I instanciate both classes like `ClassA ca = new ClassA(); ClassB cb = new ClassB();` and set `ca.Number = 12`; I would expect `cb.Number` to be also 12 but it's 0

Comment: @Ben: Why would you expect that? Dependency properties are always declared as static fields for the class, but the effect is always that there is a value *per instance*. Adding another owner to a dependency property just means the *declaration* of the property belongs to two classes; each instance of either of the two classes will still have its individual *values* for the dependency property.

Comment: @Ben That's an incorrect assumption and not what `AddOwner` supposed to do.

Comment: By "it would make it impossible to create multiple instances of the same class that all have their 'own' dependency property" I mean that according to my current understanding `ca2.Number != ca1.Number` would be impossible (`ClassA ca1 = new ClassA(); ClassA ca2 = new ClassA()`)

Comment: @Ben: `ca2.Number != ca.1Number` is *always* possible for a dependency property `Number` declared on `ClassA`, but that is already the case without using `AddOwner` anywhere.

Comment: Do you really want to share the Property or just the value that is stored in it?

Comment: @Ben: Assuming there are five instances A, B, C, D, E of `ClassA`, and five instances U, V, X, Y, Z of `ClassB` - do you want *all* these 10 instances to have the same value for the `Number` property? Or do you want *pairs* of instances of `ClassA` and `ClassB` to have the same value? In the latter case, how do you determine which instance of `ClassA` should be paired with which instance of `ClassB`?

Comment: @O. R. Mapper: I want to share the value across _all_ these 10 (A, B, C, D, E, U, V, X, Y, Z) instances (and especially use the property changed event).

Comment: @Ben: Ooh, ok. I think you should make that clearer in your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the purpose of DependencyProperties.

They are basically a *Property Definition*, without a property *Value*.

They define things like name, type, default value, location of the value, etc however they do not contain the actual value itself. This allows the value to be provided with a binding pointing to any other property in any other location.

Your best bet is to probably just create a property that is backed by a singleton property.

```
public int Number 
{
    get { return MySingleton.Number; }
    set { MySingleton.Number = value; }
}
```

**Edit**

Based on comments below where you say you want all instances of the object to respond to change notifications from any of the other objects, you'd want to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) on your singleton object, and subscribe to it's `PropertyChange` event in each class that uses that value.

For example,

```
public ClassA
{
    public ClassA()
    {
        MySingleton.PropertyChanged += Singleton_PropertyChanged;
    }

    void Singleton_PropertyChanged(object sender, NotifyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // if singleton's Number property changed, raise change 
        // notification for this class's Number property too
        if (e.PropertyName == "Number")
            OnPropertyChanged("Number");
    }

    public int Number 
    {
        get { return MySingleton.Number; }
        set { MySingleton.Number = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Rachel. I understood DependencyProperties (in simple terms) as a "reference" or "key" to the actual value. Anyways... Are you suggesting the create a Singleton which holds the DependencyProperty plus its value and access the singleton across multiple classes? Can you please provide a little bit more example code?

Comment: @Ben I'm suggesting you don't use a DependencyProperty at all. They are used when you want to use the value from another dynamic location, and in your case you want to always use the same value from the same location. I would just use a standard public property on each class which references a singleton object in the get/set methods.

Comment: The location stays the same, but the value changes. I want to use a dependency property because I want to use the property changed event across all classes/instances that work with the shared value.

Comment: @Ben In that case, you'd need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your singleton object, and have every object subscribe to the singleton's `PropertyChanged` event. I'll update my answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution to what you want here is to use another class where you store that 
value. e.g.

```
public class SomeValueStore : IValueStore
{
    int myValue {get; set;}
}
```

Then, whereever you need that value, you can use Dependency injection to get it.

somewhere at Bootstrapper:

```
RootContainer.Register<IValueStore>(new SomeValueStore);
```

and in code:

```
var valueStore = RootContainer.Resolve<IValueStore();
valueStore.myValue = 42;
```

This is just an idea (And I know we have a ServiceLocator here).

Perhaps you can store a reference to that ValueStore somewhere where you
can get it from both classes you need it as a simple solution.

```
public SomeClassYouHaveAccessToFromBothSides
{
    public IValueStore _store = new SomeValueStore();
}
```

Please excuse me. I do not have access to my repo / visual studio right now
so I cannot give better example. But I think the underlying idea is clear.